# Sending email without Intent.createChooser

Tags: android, email

I would like my email to be sent without having the email client ot open on the Android screen.

my code is standard:

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{addresses});
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

How to?
Thanks.
Charles.

Answer (score 1):

Refer [This](http://www.anddev.org/email_send_intent_intentchooser-t3295.html). might be helpful

It will open up email application in real device. In emulator it doesn't work, many people have faced this & found this working.

-Thanks

Comment: i think it will open email client on android device.

Comment: answer is here         http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/25edfecbeb5202d1