# Intent chhoser in sending mail

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to send email on the gmail account.
When i use this it prompts a dialog which asks to select type like facebook, gmail, yahooo...

Before this i am using intent chooser now i am using just intent in the following code.
It calls intent chooser for the first time.. but i want default selection is gmail account

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("image/jpeg");
        intent.setType("application/octet-stream");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailAddressList);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, emailSubject);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailText);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+image_id));
        startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the `intent.setType("image/jpeg")` and `intent.setType("application/octet-stream")` to the following:

```
intent.setType("plain/text");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i want to send image to... Is plain text will work with plain text too.

Comment: I know that you want to sent the image too, but the pain/text MIME is only checked by gmail app so maybe adds the image through the EXTRA_STREAM param. Have you tried it?

Comment: But i am getting image from the resource and when i write this intent.setType("plain/text") than i cant able to get the extension.. If i want to get the image extension than i have to write intent.setType("image/jpeg")

Comment: Yes i tried it it works but the file extension not append with the image file and the email received in attachment is not an image.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to use Gmail as default client from application without user intervention.

If you really want this to happen, you will have to find some other alternative which is nothing but Java Mail Api. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-a) which elaborates more on this.

Also read following articles to get more insights on this:

1. [Sending email without Intent.createChooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386971/sending-email-without-intent-createchooser)
2. [How to use JavaMail API in android to send mail from any email Account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253208/how-to-use-javamail-api-in-android-to-send-mail-from-any-email-account)